# A combinatorial game about stones

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

There are some piles of stones.

Two players move in turn.
One can remove a stone from a pile or merge two piles in a move.
The player that removes the last stone wins.

With the number of stones in each pile given, how to know who will win?

Comment: In fact, I got a conclusion, but I don't know how to prove it. Suppose there are $p$ piles, $k$ piles that contain only one stone, and a total of $n$ stones. If $n \le p+1$, the first player lose when $k\bmod{3}=0$. If $n>p+1$ the first player lose when $p+n$ is odd and $k$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Only by taking a pile which consists of a single stone can a player change the parity (see Brian's hint). Is there a strategy for a player who is winning on parity which avoids either player taking a single stone until the last move?

What happens when the initial position has a single pile of size 1?

What happens when there are several piles of size 1 in the initial position?